# TFJS-Node: How to load model from url?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I want to load a model from an url in node.

This works in the broser:

```
mobileNet = await tf.loadModel('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_0.25_224/model.json');
```

But not in node

> Error: browserHTTPRequest is not supported outside the web browser without a fetch polyfill

I can do get request with node like this:

```
const https = require('https');
https.get(mobileNetUrl, (res) => {
    ...
});
```

The get request returns an Object with a modelTopology and a weightManifest. How could I create a model from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line to your code

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

`tf.loadModel` uses `fetch` under the hood. But `fetch` is not natively supported in nodeJs. That is why the pollyfill should be imported.