# I can't load model from file:// with @tensorflow/tfjs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I am building an npm package that loads a pretrained tensorflow model and makes some prediction.

When i do `tf.loadLayersModel()` with `tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')` i have no problem. Unfortunately, that library seem problematic upon installation. 
I tried using instead `tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs)`. Although, i get the following error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: browserHTTPRequest is not supported outside the web browser without a fetch polyfill.

This is my code:

```
 // Load ML model
  tf.loadLayersModel("file://" + __dirname + "mymodel/model.json").then(
    model => {
      }
    }
  );
```

Is there a way i can work this around?.

Comment: @Seblor Now sure you're right about URL: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#native_file_system_nodejs_only_2 Maybe you have 3 slashes in your path, but only 2 is allowed?

Comment: Ah my bad, then.

Comment: I don't get that with the 3 slashes can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFJS-Node: How to load model from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665923/tfjs-node-how-to-load-model-from-url)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` when you working on Node.js.
Just don't require `@tensorflow/tfjs` and everything will work as expected.

But if you really want to only use `@tensorflow/tfjs`, then just add `tfjs-node-save`

```
npm install --save tfjs-node-save
```

and use it in your script

```
require('tfjs-node-save');
```

Answer (score 1):

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: browserHTTPRequest is not supported outside the web browser without a fetch polyfill.

You need a polyfill for fetch if you're using `@tensorflow/tfjs` instead of `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Comment: Added that and now i get this error:
Error: Request for file://D:\Users\panos\Desktop\eslint-generator/mymodel/model.json failed due to error: TypeError: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported

Comment: You have to serve the model files using a local server since you are not using node binding. Consider this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639919/load-tensorflow-js-model-from-local-file-system-in-javascript